# Oracle - Update case when then else part do nothing

Tags: oracle

In Oracle DB, have a table called Details. The Details table data shown below.

```
Name | Age
--------------
 xxx  |  4
 yyy  |  1
 zzz  |  10
```

Required to swap ages from 4 to 1 & 1 to 4 without disturbing age 10. I used below query which yields error in Oracle sql developer.

```
update details set age= case when age=4 then 1 
when age=1 then 4 end;
```

tried below query also:

```
update details set age= case when age=4 then 1 
when age=1 then 4 
else null end;


Error report for both queries:
SQL Error: ORA-01407: cannot update ("DETAILS"."AGE") to NULL
01407. 
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict the update just for rows with age 1 or 4

```
update details 
  set age= case 
            when age=4 then 1 
            when age=1 then 4 
           end
where age in (1,4)
```

This will work as well but you will do unnecessary updates

```
update details 
set age= case 
           when age=4 then 1 
           when age=1 then 4 
           else age 
          end
```